# Json ignore class name not the attribute

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jackson

I have a requirement in one of my java rest API in which I had to prepare a list of object in below manner.

user id will be an Integer field or an alphanumeric field.

```
{  
   "userId":{  
      "username":"somevalue",
      "userGroupId":"12345678"
   },

   "useridN":{  
      "userGroupId":"somevalue",
      "address":{  
         "street":null,
         "streetnumber":null,
         "floor":null,
         "floorside":null,
         "city":null,
         "zipCode":null,
         "houseLetter":null,

      }
   }
}
```

I could not find any better POJO class to make the structure like above.
I am using jackson libraries.

Can anybody help me to find suitable structure to design a pojo class for above requriement

Answer (score 1):

You can try http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org to generate your java class file from json